# To what extent does blender speed dissolve table salt + cold tap water?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have a question about my Chemistry Stack Exchange post: [To what extent does blender speed dissolve table salt + cold tap water?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/171088/to-what-extent-does-blender-speed-dissolve-table-salt-cold-tap-water)

### Why does my question need "details or clarity"? [Buck Thorn](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/171088/to-what-extent-does-blender-speed-dissolve-table-salt-cold-tap-water#comment359836_171088) grokked it!

At home daily, I need to mix my table salt + COLD tap water. **[The final solution shall be COLD](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/66142)!** As ["Marine salts dissolve faster and more thoroughly when added to circulating water," I "use a powerhead to speed up mixing time](https://www.bulkreefsupply.com/content/post/md-2016-12-how-to-mix-saltwater-in-5-easy-steps) — my [Vitamix 7500 blender](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LQT9DYS).

[image]

Speed 10, or even 9, feels like overkill for a solid as soluble as table salt! I shall avoid higher blender speeds, because the faster speeds shall strain my blender's motor! To lessen engine strain, I prefer to blend more slowly at a lower setting for a longer time, than blending more fastly at a higher setting for a shorter time.

##### 1. How do I deduce which setting suffices for mixing table salt + COLD tap water?

#### 2. Am I correct that blending at the lower setting (e.g. 1) for longer yields the same result as blending at a higher setting (e.g. 2) for shorter time?

> [Never add salt mix quickly or all at once, this will cause precipitation. Always add it slowly, one cup at a time. Also, be sure to add salt into the water and never water into the salt.  In other words, fill the container 100% with water first, then add the appropriate amount of salt into the water. If you try to measure out the salt first, then fill it up with water, precipitation will occur.](https://www.bulkreefsupply.com/content/post/md-2015-11-how-to-mix-saltwater-for-your-reef-aquarium)

Comment: This was closed because it is unclear what you are asking (not to mention it seems an advert for the blender or sea salt mix supplier and the "chemistry" question is nonsensical). You discuss "table salt" but then later "sea salt" with a link to aquarium supplies. Which one is it?

Comment: Also, please mind how you format the question.

Answer (score 2):

*You might reformulate your questions as follows below. I still think this question needs editing as it has two subjects, the solubility of pre-mixed dry sea salt mix, and the dissolution rate of salts at different stirring rates. The latter is not really much of a question, as you can answer this by trial and error with your particular blender. Obviously (hopefully) faster stirring will lead to faster dissolution*.

At home daily, I need to mix marine salt and cold tap water.
As marine salts dissolve faster and more thoroughly when added to circulating water, I use a blender to dissolve it.

Higher speeds feel like overkill for a solid as soluble as table salt.

1. How do I deduce which setting suffices for mixing table salt + COLD tap water?
2. Am I correct that blending at the lower setting (e.g. 1) for longer yields the same result as blending at a higher setting (e.g. 2) for shorter time?

The following instructions [follow with the sea salt](https://%20https://www.bulkreefsupply.com/content/post/md-2015-11-how-to-mix-saltwater-for-your-reef-aquarium):

> Never add salt mix quickly or all at once, this will cause precipitation. Always add it slowly, one cup at a time. Also, be sure to add salt into the water and never water into the salt.  In other words, fill the container 100% with water first, then add the appropriate amount of salt into the water. If you try to measure out the salt first, then fill it up with water, precipitation will occur.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my post. Can you reopen please? I want to keep more sentences, to provide more context. More context is better than less!

Comment: @User You still haven't explained what kind of salt you have. You write initially that you want to dissolve table salt (which is trivial) and later about marine salt. Which is it? Also, what speed to use on a blender to dissolve table salt is not a good question here. It is a question of trial and error, the amount of salt you are dissolving and the temperature of the water (which determine solubility and solubilization rate), and of your patience. Specify the problem and application in more detail. There is no clear problem. Why not use a little hot water to dissolve initially, then dilute?

Comment: @User this link: https://www.bulkreefsupply.com/content/post/md-2016-12-how-to-mix-saltwater-in-5-easy-steps refers to a marine salt mix which would have different properties from table salt, as it contains other salts in addition to table salt.

Comment: apology! I thought "marine salt" is just sea salt. no, I mean just table salt. I wrote "store bought table salt" in the first sentence. Not marine salt! Dr. Smit warned me to use NO warm or hot water at all, not even initially! Dr. Smit advised cold water! Can you edit my question for me please? Faster than you writing out what to edit, my copy pasting your edit, and you disliking my edit.

Comment: Ok, basically what you are looking for is information on the dissolution rate of common table salt (NaCl) as a function of temperature. The rest is a question about how best to operate a particular mixing device to speed up dissolution of table salt. Those are more engineering questions than chemistry, although chemical principles are involved (dissolution, diffusion). You might want to ask this in the engineering stack exchange site as it is not a good fit for this site. What is wrong with adding hot water to table salt? (Note also that medical questions are also off topic here.)

Comment: Trial and error is the answer. Measure a known amount of salt and water at a controlled temperature and place in blender. Set blender on to low setting. Use a timer to measure time to dissolution: Every now and then check whether there is any salt undissolved. When all dissolved record the time. Repeat a few times with the same amount to obtain an average. Repeat also with other speeds and maybe amounts of salt. Tabulate and plot and decide how long you are willing to wait, then use that speed. Done.